# past simple with until

Tags: past-simple

> A kangaroo injured Australian politician Shane Rattenbury in the Australian capital, Canberra, on Thursday. Mr. Rattenbury was taking a morning jog in the Canberra suburb of Ainslie when the kangaroo surprised him, and in the ensuing confrontation Mr. Rattenbury was scratched several times on the leg.
>   By Mr Rattenbury’s account, the kangaroo was an eastern grey kangaroo, which is a common species in Australia. Neither the kangaroo nor Mr. Rattenbury **saw**  each other until they were  close, when they both were surprised by each other. The kangaroo, which had been behind a hedge, then started hopping around and Rattenbury ducked for cover.

I think that it will be better to write had seen instead of saw  because the action of not seeing took place before they were close  , as soon as they were close enough they could see each other. There was a change

Comment: Did this come from a news article somewhere? If so, please cite or link to the source.

Comment: Both tenses are possible since the sequence of events is chronological; there's no special need for the past perfect here in my (NNS) opinion.

Comment: 'had seen' or 'had yet seen' could be a replacement.  Different tense, but they mean the same thing in this context.

Answer (score 1):

Either "had seen" or "saw" would be acceptable here, but I like it the way it is.  There is no special focus on the situation, just a sequence of events.